# trying to call retrofit execute in a method | NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, retrofit, viewmodel

I am trying to call the login interface in a method.

I am using the android studio login template for login.

```
public class LoginDataSource {

    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {

        try {
            Response<LoggedInUser> response = API.getLoginService().login(username, password).execute();

                return new Result.Success<>(response.body());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
        }
    }

    public void logout() {
        // TODO: revoke authentication
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are calling this method from the main thread(UI thread), the main thread is not made for heavy processing and network calls, if you want to call an API, then call it from a background thread.

`execute()` method runs in the main thread needed async task to put this in the background thread or you can use `enqueue()` method, `enqueue` will call the API from the background thread.

Comment: use logging interceptor to or any other way to print the response, check what you are getting, and let me know